# Drop redundant value labels

Tags: stata, label

I have a part of big dataset. Many variables contain value labels, but such values are not present in this part of dataset. I would like to remove the redundant value labels from the dataset. I tried to do that in Stata using various approaches but did not succeed.

Apparently this does not work:

```
label drop X if X == 1
```

Added text: So far I came with the following solutions which are not perfect because I need to repeat this exercise again and again in future:

First (semi-manual):

```
fre var
di r(lab_valid);
label drop var;
label define var 1 "Label 1" 2 "Label 2" 3 "label 3", modify.
```

Second (X is a label code that need to be kept. The problem is that I have multiple that need to be kept):

```
labellist var
local min = r(var_min)
local max = r(var_max)
forval i = `min'/`max' {
    if `i' != X {
        label define var `i' "", modify
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No "apparently" about it: that is not legal code, nor does it even make sense in principle. At best `label drop` drops named labels, but the name of the labels and the name of any variable they are attached to do not coincide unless you have set it up that way.

This is dubious:

1. Stata doesn't use a lot of memory storing value labels in most cases. Much of the point of value labels is that a value label need only be stored once.
2. This kind of question seems to imply that value labels were set up before you came along and that each value might find an observation to stick to. That was very possibly wise thinking.

This is dangerous:

1. The same value labels may be used for more than one variable, so in principle you need to check for use on all the variables that use a particular set.
2. You need to worry about what might happen if you `append` or `merge` with similar datasets. That could lead to more mess than you want.
3. Less biting, but also worth mentioning, is that a value label that isn't in the data  might still be useful for graphical purposes.

So, I don't advise what you're thinking of. You could try a `decode` of each variable with value labels and then an `encode` based on those values. But the value labels wouldn't necessarily be in a desired order. By default `encode` would use alphabetical order and you end up with nonsense like `1 "Acceptable" 2 "Bad" 3 "Good"` or `1 "Agree" 2 "Disagree" 3 "Neutral"`. It's possible to imagine ending up with more labels than you started with.

There are other ways to do it properly, but it's a small project.

Executive summary: Sorry, but that doesn't sound like a good idea.

EDIT: This is hacked out of `dataex`. It should work for various versions <15.

```
*! 1.0.0 NJC 11apr2018 
program showvaluelabelsused 
    version 15 
    syntax [varlist] 

    quietly ds, has(vallabel) 

    foreach v in `r(varlist)'  {
        local l : value label `v'
        local vlabels : list vlabels | l
    }

    foreach vl in `vlabels' {
        local alllevels
        qui ds , has(vallabel `vl')
        local vlist `r(varlist)'
        foreach v in `vlist' {
            qui levelsof `v', local(levels) missing
            local alllevels : list alllevels | levels
            dis as res "label values `v' `vl'"
        }

        foreach n in `alllevels' {
            local ltext : label `vl' `n', strict
            if `"`ltext'"' != "" {
                if strpos(`"`ltext'"',char(34)) dis as res `"label def `vl' `n' `"`ltext'"', modify"'
                else dis as res `"label def `vl' `n' "`ltext'", modify"'
            }
        }
    }
end 

. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. showvaluelabelsused
foreign
label values foreign origin
label def origin 0 "Domestic", modify
label def origin 1 "Foreign", modify

. keep if foreign
(52 observations deleted)

. showvaluelabelsused
label values foreign origin
label def origin 1 "Foreign", modify

. webuse nlswork, clear
(National Longitudinal Survey.  Young Women 14-26 years of age in 1968)

. showvaluelabelsused
label values race racelbl
label def racelbl 1 "white", modify
label def racelbl 2 "black", modify
label def racelbl 3 "other", modify

. keep if race == 2
(20,483 observations deleted)

. showvaluelabelsused
label values race racelbl
label def racelbl 2 "black", modify
```

Comment: Dear Nick, thank you for your answer and advise. I totally understand your concern, but I do not want to go to the reasoning why I need to get rid of redundant (not used) value labels. I spend a lot of time on that today, but could not come to a better solution than process variables one by one semi-manually: fre var;
di r(lab_valid); label drop var; label define var "Label 1" 2 "Label 2" 3 "label 3", modify.

Comment: Your choice, but I won't spend time writing a program to implement a bad idea.

Comment: Well, if so, I think it worth the explanation, so that you know it is not for nothing. I need to provide small datasets to students in Excel format and codebook separately. Sometimes codebooks are extremely long when there are >500 value labels for some variables. That is why for small derived datasets for educational purposes I need to shorten the codebooks by removing redundant value labels.

Comment: Explaining the real problem makes it more nearly soluble. Reduce your dataset to example dataset, then run `dataex` to produce `input` and other code to reproduce it and `save` what results.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, thank you! It is indeed a good solution. The only problem that the `dataex` can be run with a very few variables due to linesize limit for input command, so I need to run that in parts (~15 variables per run).

Comment: See now a hack to show value labels being used in the data currently in memory.

Comment: Nick, thank you for investing your time in that. The provided program is just exactly what I needed.